# Как проверить работоспособность кода?

Tags: javascript

Не могу понять что нужно выводить в консоль чтобы проверить работоспособность кода.

```js
class Human {
    constructor(name,sex) {}
}
const humanInfo = new Human('Dmitriy','male');
const humanInfo1 = new Human('Andrew','male');
const humanInfo2 = new Human('Nasty','female');
const humanInfo3 = new Human('Dina','female');

class Flat {
    #arrayOfResidents = [];
    getResident (humanInfo) {
        this.#arrayOfResidents.push(humanInfo);
    }
}
const flatInfo = new Flat();
flatInfo.getResident(humanInfo);

const flatInfo1 = new Flat();
flatInfo1.getResident(humanInfo1);

const flatInfo2 = new Flat();
flatInfo2.getResident(humanInfo2);

const flatInfo3 = new Flat();
flatInfo3.getResident(humanInfo3);

class House {
    #arrayOfFlats = [];
    constructor(maxQuantityOfFlats) {
        this.maxQuantityOfFlats = maxQuantityOfFlats;
    }
    addFlat (flatInfo) {
        if (this.maxQuantityOfFlats >= 4) {
            this.#arrayOfFlats.push(flatInfo);
        }
        else {
            console.log('Недостаточно квартир в данном доме')
        }
    }
}
const houseInfo = new House(10);
houseInfo.addFlat(flatInfo);
houseInfo.addFlat(flatInfo3);
const houseInfo1 = new House(7);
houseInfo1.addFlat(flatInfo1);
houseInfo1.addFlat(flatInfo2);
```

Comment: В консоль надо выводить "переменные", которые вы хотите проверить и сравнивать полученный результат с ожидаемым.

Comment: Для проверки работоспособности не обязательно что-то выводить в консоль. А можно использовать отладку кода (см. в ответе дубликате)